# OSX Set Page size

Tags: macos, memory, assembly

How would I go about setting the page size in memory for OS X Yosemite?

If I enter `pagesize` into terminal I get `4096`. Is there a way I can modify this?

Comment: If you're not sure what the page size is, what makes you think you want to change it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer: **No.**

The page size is specific to your architecture and cannot generally be changed by a user at run-time. Intel x86 processors all use a page size of 4 KiB.

---

Longer answer:

Your CPU may also support larger pages, like 2 MiB, and 1 GiB. (See [Huge Pages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_(computer_memory)#Huge_pages) on Wikipedia.) However, it is completely up to your OS kernel to manage how pages of memory are mapped into various address spaces.

Few userspace APIs concern themselves with the platform's page size. The ones that do, however (e.g. [`mmap`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html)) are written to the least-common-denominator of the available page sizes, because you can't guarantee that a larger page size will be used for a particular page. For this reason, the "page size" exposed to userspace is a simple single value, like 4 KiB.

On Linux, there is some "control" over this mechanism. Check out:

- [Huge pages part 1 (Introduction)](http://lwn.net/Articles/374424/) [LWN.net]
- [Huge pages part 2: Interfaces](http://lwn.net/Articles/375096/) [LWN.net]
- [`hugetlbpage.txt`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/hugetlbpage.txt) [kernel.org]
- [Hugepages](https://wiki.debian.org/Hugepages) [Debian Wiki]

I have no idea if OS X supports this. Searches for OS X hugepages came up thin.

Comment: Okay, the longer answer is what I am trying to do. Are there any hooks into the OS's memory management system?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with OSX's memory management. But what exactly are you trying to do? Also, see my edit regarding linux and huge pages

Comment: Using Linux is an option, I will look into that, Thanks!

Comment: Related question on SuperUser: [Which CPUs support 1GB pages?](http://superuser.com/q/710870/101823)